# How to save a graph with ggsave in a Windows folder structure?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

I have following folder structure.

`C:\Folders\Subfolder\Sub-Subfolder\Sub-Sub-Subfloder` and also have file called `grphics01.pdf` and I want to save `grphics01.pdf` file to this `C:\Folders\Subfolder\Sub-Subfolder\Sub-Sub-Subfloder` folder.

My current working directory is different than this folder structure.

When I am using following code:

```
directory <- "C:\\Folders\\Subfolder\\Sub-Subfolder\\Sub-Sub-Subfloder\\"
ggsave(filename = here(directory, "graphics01.pdf"), width = 30, height = 20, units = "cm", 
        device = cairo_pdf())
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in grDevices::pdf(file = filename, ..., version = version) : 
cannot open file 'C:\Folders\Subfolder\Sub-Subfolder\Sub-Sub-Subfloder\/graphics.pdf'
```

As per my understanding, `Sub-Sub-Subfloder\/graphics.pdf` the front-slash in-front of the file name is causing the error.

Is there any way can I convert this front-slash to a back-slash?

I have to resolve the issue by using "here" package and defining

```
ggsave(path = directory, filename = "graphics01.pdf, device = pdf)
```

But I am getting the same eror.

Comment: Try without the last "\\", i.e. `directory <- "C:\\Folders\\Subfolder\\Sub-Subfolder\\Sub-Sub-Subfloder"`.

Comment: @stefan still getting the same error, the system is putting a front-slash in-front of the file name `/graphics01.pdf`

Comment: Hm. Weird. The forward slash is not the issue. I just checked on a Windows machine and worked fine. Perhaps you you check that the folder exists, e.g. using `dir(directory)`? At least `Subfloder` looks like a typo to me.

Comment: @stefan, the folder exists and it is not a typo `C:\Folders\Subfolder\Sub-Subfolder\Sub-Sub-Subfloder/graphics01.pdf` this is returning as the full path. Every level it is back slash only in front of the filename there is front slash.